# XE7 copy text to clipboard

Tags: delphi, clipboard, delphi-xe7

http://www.swissdelphicenter.com/torry/showcode.php?id=640 has an example for copy list item to clipboard.  The code works on WIN-XP and Delphi 7.  It doesn't work on XE7.  I'm guessing the 16 bit char or string type is causing issues because the data in the list came from a USB peripheral that works with 8 bit characters.
But the code looks correct.

Comment: That code is terrible. It uses short strings. Don't use that code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy to clipboard code should look like this:

```
procedure ListBoxToClipboard(ListBox: TListBox; CopyAll: Boolean);
var
  i: Integer;
  s: string;
begin
  s := '';
  for i := 0 to ListBox.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if CopyAll or ListBox.Selected[i] then
      s := s + ListBox.Items[i] + sLineBreak;
  end;
  ClipBoard.AsText := s;
end;
```

**Note:** I changed CopyAll logic from original code, because it didn't make much sense to me. Either all items have to be copied to clipboard, or only selected ones. whether or not ListBox has MultiSelect or not should not make any difference.

Comment: @jc You might wonder whether or not it is worth retaining `if not Assigned(ListBox)`. I know that I would not.

Comment: @David Agreed, this Assigned is just superfluous.

Answer (score 8):

In order to copy the ListBox content into clipboard, you can use the following code:

```
uses
  Vcl.Clipbrd;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Clipboard.AsText := ListBox1.Items.Text;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
procedure ListBoxToClipBoard(lb:TListBox; copyAll:Boolean);
var
  i: integer;
  sb: TStringBuilder;
begin
  sb := TStringBuilder.Create;
  try
    for i := 0 to lb.Items.Count -1  do
      if copyAll or lb.Selected[i] then
        sb.AppendLine(lb.Items[i]);
    Clipboard.AsText := sb.ToString;
  finally
    sb.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.Code might answer the question but little more explanation might help out the fellow programmers to understand how it works.